# Event with confirm lost after postback raised for other control

Tags: asp.net, events, updatepanel, postback, confirm

I have this scenario

TextBox with AutoPostBack=true and server-side code to manage text changes.

Button with server-side set confirm and code to manage.
    btnSend.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return confirm('Confirm message')");
    ....

Everything is inside an UpdatePanel

When the user is writing at the TextBox and, whithout leave the textbox focus, click the button, the confirm appears, and behind the inputTextAnswer_TextChanged is raised and executed. Then the page has processed the PostBack so if user click 'Ok' at the confirm nothing is executed. User need to click again to really execute the button code.

Is there a way to run the inputTextAnswer_TextChanged code (should be executed first) and then the button code. Important: Not always should be executed one after another, just when the user fill the textbox field and then click the button

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if someoane has the same problem, my solution. Instead of leave the confirm associated with return to the button, just do the postback manually by javascript. Then the textbox change events executes and when user click 'ok' we force the postback and the execution of the button code.

this piece of code on serverside

```
btnSend.Attributes.Add("onClick", "confirmSend();");
```

this on aspx

```
<script>
function confirmSend() {
    var agree = confirm('confirm message');
    if (agree) {
         __doPostBack('btnSend', '');
   }
  }
</script>
```